# Why is this comparison failing?

Tags: python, numbers, comparison, typeerror

```
print("Enter the number you want to test")
Num1 = input("Enter your number here:")
if (Num1%1 == '0' and Num1%Num1 == '0'):
    print ("This number is prime number")
else:
    print("This number is nor prime number")
```

This is failing with an error of `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. What is the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: While others are answering what the error means and how to fix it, I'll point out that your algorithm for figuring out whether a number is prime is flawed; the if statement will always return true for any integer.

Comment: What's the point of `Num1 % 1`? All integers are equal to 0 modulo 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a `string` , you should convert it to `int`:

```
Num1 = int(input("Enter your name here:"))
```

And `if` parts changed to :

```
if (Num1%1 == 0 and Num1%Num1 == 0):
```

However your code logic for realize that a number is prime or not is not correct , you should check that `number` has a factor or not , you should write a `for` loop  through it's lower numbers and realize that.it's simple but I think it's better for you that write it yourself.